# Calculate a date by the amount of months passed by in bash

Tags: date, awk

I have list with two items, `title` and `months`.

```
MS4.2.8|48, 60 
MS4.2.9|60 
MS4.2.10|52 
MS4.3.1|3 
MS4.3.2|12 
MS4.3.3|9 
MS4.3.4|12 
MS4.3.5|24,36,48,60 
MS4.3.6|24,36,48,60 
MS4.3.7|24 
MS4.3.8|18
```

The start period is "2021-09-01".
I need a list with `title` and date calculated on the amount of months passed by since the start period. The month period can be set multiple times, for each month-period there should be a new line.

For example:

```
MS4.2.8|2025-08-01
MS4.2.8|2026-08-01 
MS4.2.9|2026-08-01 
MS4.2.10|2026-01-01 
MS4.3.1|2021-11-01 
MS4.3.2|2022-08-01 
MS4.3.3|2022-05-01 
.
.
.
```

Comment: `How...?` Read one line. Split on `|`. Take second part. Split on `,`, ignore spaces. For each element, add to `2021-09-01` the count of months and convert to `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Then for each result, display the first part from `|` splitting, then display `|` character then the result.

Comment: ok - I rephrased it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk' BEGIN{OFS=FS="|"}
     {n=split($2,a,",");
      for(i=1;i<=n;++i) print $1,strftime("%F",mktime("2021 " (08+a[i]) " 01 0 0 0"))
     }' file
```

the method makes use of GNU awk extensions `mktime` and `strftime`.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for mktime() and strftime().